# argparse argument nargs description

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I am using argparse and this code

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--client', nargs='*', action='store', help='Client mode, connect to [ hostname/address or localhost | port or 8080 | protocol or TCP ]')
```

shows this on help page

```
  -c [CLIENT [CLIENT ...]], --client [CLIENT [CLIENT ...]]
                        Client mode, connect to [ hostname/address or
                        localhost | port or 8080 | protocol or TCP ]
```

How can I make it more like following?

```
  -c [host [port]], --client [host [port]]
                        Client mode, connect to [ hostname/address or
                        localhost | port or 8080 | protocol or TCP ]
```

Comment: So you want to allow any number of clients, each of which can have up to three parameters?

Comment: I not sure why this was closed or why the `duplicate` answers it.  What was your problem?  I was going to suggest `metavar=('host','port')` to refine the labeling.  But if you don't like the open ended `*`, there's not much you can do.  There isn't an `nargs` to restrict the input to a [0,1,2] range.  I can reopen this if you refine your question.

Comment: `metavar` seems to be what I was asking. Thank you guys.